# How to correctly query to Entity with nHibernate Component

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have [schema](http://saddo.ru/temp/2009-11-21_031554.png), with such [mapping](http://temp.saddo.ru/ReportsStock.Model.hbm.xml).

Next code don't work:

```
IList<User> userList = session.CreateCriteria<User>()
                              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Login", login))
                              .List<User>();
```

Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Full stacktrace: [link](http://temp.saddo.ru/stackTrace2.png)

Comment: Could you post the full exception stack trace? Cannot cast what type to what type?

Comment: http://temp.saddo.ru/stackTrace2.png

Comment: In your mapping instead of this: <class name="User" table="[User]">, you can use <class name="User" table="User"> with that in the mapping file <property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">auto-quote</property> if you use NH 2.1 (or 2.0 don't remember)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
IList<User> userList = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User))
                  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Login", login))
                  .List<User>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug in mapping:

```
<component name="UserRole">
  <property name="Role" column="role" not-null="true" type="System.String" />
</component>
```

should:

```
<component name="UserRole">
  <property name="Role" column="role" not-null="true" />
</component>
```